# keys with multiple values in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list (I have omitted some values from the list):

```
all_examples=   ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5',...]
```

I need to create a dictionary such that a key has multiple values.

```
dict = {"A":[1,1], "B":[2,1]}
```

I looked for some possible solution, but couldn't make it work on mine.

Comment: Are you looking for the right structure, or how to generate it from the list that you have ? I would recommand a structure like this: dict = {"A":[1,1], "B":[2,1]}  , instead of having values as a string

Comment: @clemkoa just made the changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for python3 you can use a dict comp, using *extended iterable unpacking* splitting each string in your list and creating a key/value paring from the split elements:

```
l = ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']

d = {k: list(map(int,rest)) for k,*rest in (s.split(",") for s in l) }
```

For python2 the syntax is not quite as nice:

```
l = ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']

d = {s[0]: map(int, s[1:] ) for s in (s.split(",") for s in l)}
```

Both should give you something like:

```
In [32]:  d = {k: list(map(int,rest)) for k,*rest in (s.split(",") for s in l) } 
In [33]: d
Out[33]: {'A': [1, 1], 'B': [2, 1], 'C': [4, 4], 'D': [4, 5]}
```

To break it down, the inner gen exp is creating our split strings:

```
In [35]: list (s.split(",") for s in l)
Out[35]: [['A', '1', '1'], ['B', '2', '1'], ['C', '4', '4'], ['D', '4', '5']]
```

Then in the python3 case in `for k,*rest in..` `k` is the first element of the lists, the `*rest` syntax basically means everything else.

```
 In [37]: for k,*rest in (s.split(",") for s in l):
              print(k, rest)
   ....:     
A ['1', '1']
B ['2', '1']
C ['4', '4']
D ['4', '5']
```

So putting it all together to create the dict using a for loop would be:

```
In [38]: d = {}

In [39]: for k,*rest in (s.split(",") for s in l):
              d[k] = list(map(int, rest))
   ....:     

In [40]: d
Out[40]: {'A': [1, 1], 'B': [2, 1], 'C': [4, 4], 'D': [4, 5]}
```

Or in the case of python2:

```
In [42]: d = {}

In [43]: for spl in (s.split(",") for s in l):
              d[spl[0]] = list(map(int,spl[1:]))
   ....:     

In [44]: d
Out[44]: {'A': [1, 1], 'B': [2, 1], 'C': [4, 4], 'D': [4, 5]}
```

Comment: You forgot to convert to integers

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Awesome, but could you explain the one in Python 3 a bit?

Comment: Nested generator expression / dict comprehension combo is pretty gnarly for this.  Recommend just to use a for loop and resist the urge to one-liner everything.

Comment: @wim, I added a couple of  for loops and the steps along the way so it should hopefully cover all bases.

Answer (score 2):

A simple & straight-forward solution:

```
result = {}
for l in all_examples:
    split_list = l.split(',')
    result[split_list[0]] = [int(val) for val in split_list[1:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A short but not so efficient solution,

```
all_examples = ['A,1,1', 'B,2,1', 'C,4,4', 'D,4,5']
d = dict((a.split(',')[0], a.split(',')[1:])for a in all_examples)
```

Comment: That is not a list comp ;)